# Creating custom terminal commands with module

Tags: npm

I am writing a node module that generates the necessary redux files. My goal is to have the end user run `npm install --save redux-file-gen`, then be able to run `redux generate store` directly from the terminal, instead of `node run ....`.

Here is the important part of my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "redux-file-gen",
  "version": "1.0.8",
  "description": "Generates necessary files for react-redux application",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  },
  "preferGlobal": "true",
  "bin": {
    "redux": "index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "colors": "^1.1.2",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.5"
  }
}
```

I can run `npm link` on my own machine to create the custom terminal command. But when I publish to npm and then install it on another machine, the `redux` command is undefined.

I tried to use `postinstall` for npm to run `npm link`, but this does not work.

As of now, in order to run my generator, the user has to run

```
node node_modules/redux-file-gen/index.js
```

Anyone has an idea how to fix this?

Here is the [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-file-gen) to the node module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the answer is. In order to be able to use the `redux` command in the terminal, I have to install the package globally. So, I just need to run

```
npm install -g redux-file-gen
```

That will allow me to use custom commands.